# Python - Strip string from html tags, leave links but in changed form

Tags: python, html

Is there a way to remove all html tags from string, but leave some links and change their representation? Example:

```
    description: <p>Animation params. For other animations, see <a href="#myA.animation">myA.animation</a> and the animation parameter under the API methods.       The following properties are supported:</p>
<dl>
  <dt>duration</dt>
  <dd>The duration of the animation in milliseconds.</dd>
<dt>easing</dt>
<dd>A string reference to an easing function set on the <code>Math</code> object. See <a href="http://example.com">demo</a>.</dd>
</dl>
<p>
```

and I want to replace

```
<a href="#myA.animation">myA.animation</a>
```

with only 'myA.animation', but

```
<a href="http://example.com">demo</a>
```

with 'demo: http://example.com'

EDIT:
Now it seems to be working:

```
def cleanComment(comment):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
    for m in soup.find_all('a'):
        if str(m) in comment:
            if not m['href'].startswith("#"):
                comment = comment.replace(str(m), m['href'] + " : " + m.__dict__['next_element'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
    comment = soup.get_text()
    return comment
```

Comment: Your examples are global rules for you html? Or it might be that some links you'll want to save but others not?

Comment: Yes, there are only two types of links.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you: `(?=href="http)(?=(?=.*?">(.*?)<)(?=.*?"(https?:\/\/.*?)"))|"#(.*?)"`

You can try it [over here](https://regex101.com/r/PgB6FI/1)

In Python:

```
import re

text = ''
with open('textfile', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

matches = re.findall('(?=href="http)(?=(?=.*?">(.*?)<)(?=.*?"(https?:\/\/.*?)"))|"#(.*?)"', text)

strings = []
for m in matches:
    m = filter(bool, m)
    strings.append(': '.join(m))

print(strings)
```

The result will look like: `['myA.animation', 'demo: http://example.com']`

Comment: Wooaa, I don't even know how to start with it in code

Comment: I've added a python example for you

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution which seems to work for me